# Golang Elasticsearch Olivere: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I'm trying to create an index using [Olivere's elastic search client for the Go language](https://github.com/olivere/elastic) version 7. 
There is an example how to achieve that on the repo's [wiki page](https://github.com/olivere/elastic/wiki/CreateIndex). I believe I'm following these steps:

```
client, err := elastic.NewClient()
if err != nil {
    // Handle error
    panic(err)
}

// Create a new index.
mapping := `{
    "settings":{
        "number_of_shards":1,
        "number_of_replicas":0
    },
    "mappings":{
        "properties":{
            "tags":{
                "type":"keyword"
            },
            "location":{
                "type":"geo_point"
            },
            "suggest_field":{
                "type":"completion",
                "payloads":true
            }
        }
    }
}`

ctx := context.Background()
createIndex, err := client.CreateIndex("twitter").BodyString(mapping).Do(ctx)
if err != nil {
    // Handle error
    panic(err)
}
if !createIndex.Acknowledged {
    // Not acknowledged
}
```

And yet I get an error:

```
Failed to parse mapping [properties]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters: [location : {type=geo_point}] [suggest_field : {payloads=true, type=completion}] [tags : {type=keyword}] [type=mapper_parsing_exception]
```

I'm aware that [mapping types have been removed in Elasticsearch V7](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/removal-of-types.html), but can't see how this should produce the mentioned error.

I also [reported](https://github.com/olivere/elastic/issues/1249) this issue in the corresponding repo.

Comment: I haven't quite migrated to 7.5 yet so maybe its a thing im not aware of, but i am unaware of the field data type `completion`, from the `suggest_field` property. You are getting an invalid mapping error, and I think this is causing it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was also not able to find such a field data type in the docs, however, even after removing the whole field the same error still occors.

Comment: Not sure what I did wrong, apparently it works when removing the mentioned field - the reason was the "payloads": true though, as stated in my answer. Thanks a lot for your help anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was

`"payloads": true`

as the creator of the library pointed out [in his answer](https://github.com/olivere/elastic/issues/1249#issuecomment-564606769) to my Github issue. After removing "payloads": true, it works.  He even created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/olivere/3e2a833bbdcc2154c1686bb7fca6b958) with the solution.

Be aware that you'll get a similar error message when you're running on elastic V6, but accidentally use the golang client for V7.